# Unable to read from text file and store into string

Tags: c++, debugging, text-files, iostream

I have a text file

```
0 Po Tom Mr 123AlphabetStreet Netherlands Wulu 123456 D01 Malaysia SmallAdventure 231112 
0 Liu Jack Mr 123AlphabetStreet Italy Spain 123456 D02 Afghanistan TriersAdventure 030214
```

I am trying to read the txt file:`Form.txt`, store each line using `getline` into the variable `foo`

This is the working program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   fstream afile;
   afile.open("Form.txt",ios::in);

   string foo;


    while (getline(afile,foo,'\n') );
    {
        cout<<foo
            <<endl;

    }

}
```

Nothing gets printed to the console output , I am expecting

```
0 Po Tom Mr 123AlphabetStreet Netherlands Wulu 123456 D01 Malaysia SmallAdventure 231112 
0 Liu Jack Mr 123AlphabetStreet Italy Spain 123456 D02 Afghanistan TriersAdventure 030214
```

Instead i get

> 

What is wrong with my code ??

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you have a `Form.txt` file in the directory of your executable?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes I have

Comment: Add a `if (!afile) cout << "Something's wrong";` before the `while` loop and let me know if it prints.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It doesnt print

Comment: What system and compiler?

Comment: What happens if you use the full path for the file name?

Comment: Windows 7 32 bit system , MS Studio 2010

Comment: Using the full path makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `while` loop:

```
while (getline(afile, foo, '\n'));
//                               ^
```

This causes the extraction to be performed but only the when the loop ends does `foo` get printed. The last extraction doesn't extract anything which is why `foo` is empty, hence the empty output.